# How to fix poor interpolation of very small rasters in viewed pdfs (evince and chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, raster

I want to create a visualization of a matrix for some academic work. I decided to go about this by having the pixels in the image correspond to the values in the matrix. I created the nice small png that follows:

[image]

When properly scaled up, you get a very reasonable image:

[image]

This is a screenshot from within inkscape. However, when I export this as a pdf, both evince and chrome do a terrible job at upscaling what should be very trivial, and instead I get something that looks like:

[image]

The pdf itself seems to scale appropriately well for printing, but unfortunately I do a lot of my editing without printing, and this looks unacceptable. I did find [this incredibly old thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/prawn-ruby/MbMsCx862iY) about people seeming to have a similar issue with chrome's pdf viewer, and the "solution" was to just upscale the raster graphics. This is a solution, but is terribly inefficient.

Is anyone aware of a way to change the pdf so that it gets upscaled appropriately? Maybe a config change in evince or chrome that will render these properly? Even a nice way to go from a raster image to a vector image might be suitable?

Comment: Have you considered drawing your matrices using vector graphics in the PDF directly instead of using bitmap graphics?

Comment: @mkl The problem with doing that is that I use a number of different tools to generate pdfs depending on where this content is being used, so it's nice to have this be independent. Second, this is generated randomly, which is probably hard to do in tex, and impossible to do (at least easily) in a vector editor or publishing platform. However, for the short term, I just wrote a python script to turn bitmap into an svg, making each pixel a rectangle. This isn't a perfect solution, but it's working well enough for my immediate purposes.

Comment: Essentuially your problem is that you want your image to look pixel'ish while usually that is not desired and PDF viewers try to interpolate. Thus, that SVG which makes clear that you indeed want sharp rectangular forms, is a better solution than you make it sound. In a PDF analog vector graphics operations may be used. I'd propose you answer your question yourself with that bitmap-to-svg approach.

Comment: @mkl I will accept that generally when people insert rasters into pdf that they want them to look smooth, they are using an inherently vector format to begin with, but this level of blurring seems a little ridiculous. Moreover, pdfs are used as a printing format akin to eps. However, when I printed this page, I got exactly the result I wanted. It seems really terrible for a pdf viewer to render a pdf different than it would be printed. I guess I'm not opposed to my solution, but it seems like one should be able to change the pdf or the viewer so this artifact doesn't appear.

Comment: In the PDF the image dictionary has an (optional) boolean entry **Interpolate**. What's its value in your PDF? It is specified as a *flag indicating whether image interpolation shall be performed by a conforming reader*.

Comment: Furthermore the specification states on interpolation: "A conforming Reader may choose to not implement this feature of PDF, or may use any specific implementation of interpolation that it wishes." Thus, different looks of interpolated images are ok by the specification.

Comment: @mkl Apparently evince does support that option, and after editing the pdf, the image interpolated as I desired. Thanks! It seems like inkscape by default sets pdfs to interpolate, even though the pdf  default is none. This does seems somewhat reasonable. I'm not sure how to get evince to set that flag, but I imagine it's not exposed.

Comment: It's also answered in this thread, which I only found after the fact http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=15829

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The comments aggregated into an answer...*

An image dictionary in a PDF has an (optional) boolean entry **Interpolate**. It is specified as a *flag indicating whether image interpolation shall be performed by a conforming reader*.

The program used by the OP to create the PDF, Inkscape, seems to have explicitly set this flag to **true**. Editing the PDF to unset this flag creates a file which looks as desired by the OP.

(This also is a solution proposed in this [Inkscape forum thread](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=15829) eventually found by the OP, which is to save the PDF with high-resolution bitmaps embedded. File -> Inkscape Preferences -> Bitmaps -> Resolution for Create Bitmap Copy, and set it to 6000 dpi)

The fact that interpolation looks different in different viewers and different output media, is by design. The PDF specification states on interpolation:

> A conforming Reader may choose to not implement this feature of PDF, or may use any specific implementation of interpolation that it wishes.

A different way to get around this problem (especially as some PDF viewers have the tendency to not really live up to the specification and e.g. interpolate ignoring that flag) would be to use vector graphics here, drawing the bitmap pixels as rectangles. The result should be optimal.

Comment: The problem with rendering the individual pixels as vector rectangles was an artifact that caused the boundaries between pixels to sometimes remain unpainted. I never figured out why that was the case, and it was unimportant given the debatebly better solution. I would have posted the code I used to do this, but it was very implementation specific, and had this artifact.

Comment: *the boundaries between pixels to sometimes remain unpainted* - did you only fill the rectangles or did you also strike them?

Comment: Only fill, but no thickness of strike would make sense. There'd be overlap.

Comment: Not striking doesn't make sense either as that leaves the border lines unpainted. You have to decide which color the border lines shall have.

Comment: I think that not striking makes perfect sense. There should be no border, the fills should perfectly align. The reason why there are white borders seems like it's probably an anti aliasing issue.

Comment: If you only fill, I.e. only paint the interior, you don't paint the border lines. Pixels exactly on border lines, therefore, remain unpainted.

Answer (score 0):

It can be different for a JPEG and a PNG in a generic viewer to be handled differently. So I support SumatraPDF and some users will complain different ways for same source. However when pixels are defined well (not lossless) they should be crisp.

Here is one same PDF file, different viewers. *NOTE* the image is a PDF of 3 pixels by 3 pixels "scaled up" within PDF, but here ALL viewers set to 50% zoom. Which then raises questions as to 50% of what? since there is disparity. Especially lower left X-pdf and Google top centre. Evince is top right Google Docs in Edge is background and IrfanView graphics viewer centre Left. Firefox PDF.js is the one without logo, lower mid right.

[image]

So where is there a problem? Well, same file same scale same image upscaled by 2 and thus a different interpretation.

[image]

So Adobe (Lower right) sets a standard and Xpdf (Lower left) holds close as does PDF.js (Lower middle right)

Sadly Evince seems to fare worst but it is a very old version.

So why are 3 others in agreement and that's because that's how a JPEG is defined as overlapping colours. But they can all handle any scale or upscaled quantity of pixels perfectly. So Chrome, Evince and SumatraPDF even IrfanView can all show perfect pixels in an upscaled PDF. So what is different about this file (apart from I rescaled more horizontal than vertical) the image is still doubled as 6 x 6 pixels at double width.

[image]

### The answer is

The **JPEG is lossless** so it's 100% quality with subsampling OFF. Then even Evince can handle the JPEG pixelation perfectly. Filesize 1.45 KB (1,493 bytes). based on 18 x 8 pixels at any scale. https://docdro.id/dAVAukU

[image: ![enter image description here]