# Python pdf interpolation under different pdf viewers

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, interpolation, pdf-viewer

I create two python (version 2.7.15) plots with `imshow` (matplotlib 2.2.3), one with `interpolation='none'`, one with `'interpolation'='nearest'`, see code below. The `'none'` pdf file appears sharp under `Evince 3.20.2` (and Acrobat Reader DC 2019.010.20069), but very blurry with `Apple Previewer`. The `'nearest'` pdf appears slightly blurry under Evince and Apple, with pixels having different sizes. Creating a `rasterized=True` plot (directly in `imshow`) for either `'none'` or `'nearest'` results in sth. similar to `rasterized=False 'nearest'`. Saving with `dpi=1000` instead of `dpi=100` does not affect `'none'` (even same file size), but improves the blurryness of `'nearest'` and the pixels become more equal-sized. Nonetheless `'nearest'` is still slightly blurrier than the Evince `'none'`.

Apple Previewer by default seems to use `'bilinear'` interpolation (at least for 'none') and I see it as a bad default (compared to `'nearest'`), especially since you can't change it (straightforwardly) in current versions. So I need to change parameters on the python side. I'd like to avoid `pcolormesh` for the plots. Any default way to obtain "perfectly" sharp imshow-generated pdf files for the different pdf viewers? Can you achieve this somehow with `'none'`? Is it `'nearest'` with high dpi?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pdf_dpi = 100

np.random.seed(100)
a = np.random.rand(100,50)

plt.imshow(a, cmap='binary', aspect='auto', interpolation='none', origin='lower')
plt.title('imshow, interpolation: none')
plt.savefig('/home/proxauf/test_pdf_plot_interpolation/imshow_none.pdf', dpi=pdf_dpi)
plt.close()

plt.imshow(a, cmap='binary', aspect='auto', interpolation='nearest', origin='lower')
plt.title('imshow, interpolation: nearest')
plt.savefig('/home/proxauf/test_pdf_plot_interpolation/imshow_nearest.pdf', dpi=pdf_dpi)
plt.close()
```

Comment: Did you try using `pcolormesh` as a comment by one of the matplotlib developpers below [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54287441/python-pdf-interpolation-under-different-pdf-viewers) suggested?

Comment: `pcolormesh` gives sharp images, but I wanted to avoid it, because my current wrapper is built on `imshow`, although it can be changed to `pcolormesh`. Somehow though I don't see how `pcolormesh`, which does not interpolate, behaves differently from `imshow` with `interpolation='none'`.

Comment: This might be related to the viewer interpretation of the PDF, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27512326